# How to properly terminate a Process prematurely?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm having an issue with properly closing a `Process` before it completes. I'm using a `ProcessBuilder` in order to create a new `Process` with one of the following two scenarios:

1. Complete the process and read it's output via a `BufferedReader`
2. Don't wait for output from the `Process`, so just give it some time to run and then terminate it (even if it's not completed, I want it to terminate).

The code I wrote so far is:

```java
public static String runCommand(List<String> commandList, boolean returnOutput) throws InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
            
        if(!returnOutput) {
            p.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            p.destroy();
            if(!p.waitFor(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                p.destroyForcibly();
            
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            System.out.println(p.isAlive());
            return null;
        }
                
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
            output.append("\n");
        }
            
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return output.toString();
}
```

The problem is related to scenario 1, because even though the Process is terminated inside the `if(!returnOutput)` since the `System.out.println` returns `false` for the `p.isAlive()` and I can get the expected results, I can see in the task manager (Windows) that it is still running...

I've checked previous answers but nothing worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the docs of [Process] (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html)#destroyForcibly: `The process may not terminate immediately. i.e. isAlive() may return true for a brief period after destroyForcibly() is called. This method may be chained to waitFor() if needed. `

Comment: Thanks @dan1st but as mentioned in the description, p.isAlive() returns false anyway in my case

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. It may be that it stops one process but task manager shows another one.

Comment: Sub-processes that write a lot of standard output can freeze if you are not consuming the output. Perhaps your process is already  I/O blocked before you call `p.destroy();`.  Post an example of a process that demonstrates the problem if you want help.

Comment: Thanks @DuncG. If the process is already blocked, then shouldn't ```p.isAlive();``` return true instead of false? Also, since I'm calling ```p.getInputStream().close()``` and ```p.getOutputStream().close()``` shouldn't the relevant resources just be released and then the Process eventually stops? Sorry, but I'm new to this and not very familiar with the Process API.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce with a sample process test case, double check the PID matches the process in task manager and see whether the output stream gives you any information.